# JSON data doesn't display in fusionchart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

i'm trying to create a chart with real data to monitor bitcoin price.
Im using binance API to receive a data from them. I have a script which shows the array in console log.

Script and Array

```
    var burl ='https://api.binance.com';

var query ='/api/v3/klines';

query += '?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&limit=2';

var url = burl + query;

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){

  // Will convert the string to something Javascript can understand
  var result = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); 
let converted=result.forEach(element => Number(element));
  // You can now use it as an array
  console.log(result);
}
ourRequest.send();
```

Here is console.log result:

```
0: Array(12)
0: 1589440260000
1: "9428.75000000"
2: "9437.16000000"
3: "9425.10000000"
4: "9434.32000000"
5: "20.06824700"
6: 1589440319999
7: "189255.69762189"
8: 403
9: "9.09331700"
10: "85755.92672934"
11: "0"
```

When i'm trying to add this array data to my chart, my values just disappear. If i hard-script the values they appear again. Where is my mistake? Also I receive respond from API it's working for 100%. Inspector doesn't show up any errors.

Here is part of the chart code.

```
{
          tooltext:
            "<b>Oct 01, 2017</b><br>Open: <b>$openDataValue</b><br>Close: <b>$closeDataValue</b><br>High: <b>$highDataValue</b><br>Low: <b>$lowDataValue</b><br>Volume: <b>$volumeDataValue</b>",
          open: converted=[1],
          high: converted=[2],
          low: converted=[3],
          close: converted=[4],
          volume: converted=[5],
          x: 1
        },
```

Edit: Currently the problem that fucntion is out of scope and I try different ways to implement it. I add JSFiddle can someone help me out where I suppose put the code, otherwise I receive error "converted is not define".

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp0ahrkw/)

Comment: I am guessing, the parsed object has string values, while the chart needs type of number

Comment: @Kourosh Is there any way how i can transform string values to number? Sorry for a dumb question I'm just started with this thing...

Comment: let myNumber= Number(stringValue)

Comment: @Hexycode just iterate over the array and convert each item to Number

Comment: @jogeshmanjhi Can you provide any example? Cause currently it's hard to me to understand.

Comment: @Hexycode for example if  a=["1","2","3","4","5"] then a.forEach(function (item, index) {
  console.log(Number(item))
});

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming the FusionChart needs type of number. The returned object from your API has string values.

Solution is to convert the string values to Number:

```
let converted=result.forEach(element => Number(element))
```

Then you can feed the chart with “converted”

— converted is an array. You should access values like this:

```
converted[index]
```

index is a value from 0 to `converted.length-1`

Comment: I tried it now and nothing happens, the numbers in chart still doesn't display

Comment: Can you post the code which you add data to your chart?

Comment: Example: open:converted[0]

Comment: Also, start from 0 not 1

Comment: if I take out = sign I receive this error Uncaught ReferenceError: converted is not define. I was trying it before as well.

Comment: That’s because you are accessing converted from a different scope. You need to define converted somewhere that your other code with chart has access to.

Comment: I add JSFiddle in main question, after spending an hour I don't understand where I suppose to put the code, cause all the time I'm getting not defined error.